# Unable to run react native IOS application on device due to codesign errors

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have a react native application (that I deploy with expo). I am trying to run on ios.

1. I had a app under a different account  under the build identifier `com.bcc.quickpass`. There, the build was working fine. I transferred the app along with the build identifier to my current account.
2. I then tried to run the app under my current account account using automated signing. The app builds but the following comes up:

[image: Trying to run the app]

Here is the XCode Log:

```
Could not launch “QuickPass”
Domain: IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain
Code: 3
Failure Reason: The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to launch com.bcc.quickpass because it has an invalid code signature, inadequate entitlements or its profile has not been explicitly trusted by the user.
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-12-06 06:01:22 +0000";
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 855031;
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = DBGLLDBLauncher;
    RawUnderlyingErrorMessage = "The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. Unable to launch com.bcc.quickpass because it has an invalid code signature, inadequate entitlements or its profile has not been explicitly trusted by the user.";
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone10,1";
    "device_osBuild" = "14.6 (18F72)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 32442;
    "operation_errorCode" = 3;
    "operation_errorDomain" = IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain;
    "operation_errorWorker" = DBGLLDBLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 5;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_runnable_swiftVersion" = "5.5.2";
    "param_runnable_type" = 2;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos15.2";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "15.2";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 11.4 (Build 20F71)
Xcode 13.2.1 (19586) (Build 13C100)
Timestamp: 2022-12-06T12:01:22+06:00
```

I also tried to build the app using expo. But codesign error occurs.

```
SQTCs-Mac-mini:ekyc-native-app sqtc$ expo run:ios --device 68f18c4f36c2943dff92345ae21bc58887477c55
...
...
CodeSign /Users/sqtc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuickPass-faybjdvqxbotkeajwmmcoupclnpg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/QuickPass.app (in target 'QuickPass' from project 'QuickPass')
    cd /Users/sqtc/Desktop/ekyc-native-app/ios
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    
    Signing Identity:     "Apple Development: Samidhya Sarker (66DM5N2A46)"
    Provisioning Profile: "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.bcc.quickpass"
                          (50d1bff7-a77b-4ecb-88d2-a0b7620625c6)
    
    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign BF6FCB75B17E29CD93717001359BB14881C0ED50 --entitlements /Users/sqtc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuickPass-faybjdvqxbotkeajwmmcoupclnpg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/QuickPass.build/Debug-iphoneos/QuickPass.build/QuickPass.app.xcent --timestamp\=none --generate-entitlement-der /Users/sqtc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuickPass-faybjdvqxbotkeajwmmcoupclnpg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/QuickPass.app
/Users/sqtc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuickPass-faybjdvqxbotkeajwmmcoupclnpg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/QuickPass.app: errSecInternalComponent
Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code



** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        CodeSign /Users/sqtc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuickPass-faybjdvqxbotkeajwmmcoupclnpg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/QuickPass.app (in target 'QuickPass' from project 'QuickPass')
(1 failure)
Build logs written to /Users/sqtc/Desktop/ekyc-native-app/.expo/xcodebuild.log
```

react-native also gives the same errors:

```
SQTCs-Mac-mini:ekyc-native-app sqtc$ npx react-native run-ios --device "SQTC’s iPhone"
^C
SQTCs-Mac-mini:ekyc-native-app sqtc$ npx react-native run-ios --device "SQTCs iPhone"
info Found Xcode workspace "QuickPass.xcworkspace"
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace QuickPass.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme QuickPass -destination id=68f18c4f36c2943dff92345ae21bc58887477c55")
▸ Running script 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders'
▸ Running script 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders'
▸ Running script '[CP-User] Generate Specs'
▸ Copying /Users/sqtc/Desktop/ekyc-native-app/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec.h
▸ Compiling FBReactNativeSpec-generated.mm
▸ Running script '[CP-User] Generate app.manifest for expo-updates'
▸ Running script '[CP-User] Generate app.config for prebuilt Constants.manifest'
▸ Running script 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders'
▸ Compiling RCTVibration.mm
▸ Compiling RCTSettingsManager.mm
▸ Compiling RCTNetworking.mm
▸ Compiling RCTLinkingManager.mm
▸ Compiling RCTImageStoreManager.mm
▸ Compiling RCTFileReaderModule.mm
▸ Compiling RCTNativeAnimatedTurboModule.mm
▸ Compiling RCTAccessibilityManager.mm
▸ Compiling RCTBlobManager.mm
▸ Compiling RCTImageLoader.mm
▸ Compiling RCTImageEditingManager.mm
▸ Compiling RCTNativeAnimatedModule.mm
▸ Compiling RCTWebSocketModule.mm
▸ Compiling RCTTiming.mm
▸ Compiling RCTStatusBarManager.mm
▸ Compiling RCTSourceCode.mm
▸ Compiling RCTRedBox.mm
▸ Compiling RCTPlatform.mm
▸ Compiling RCTLogBox.mm
▸ Compiling RCTKeyboardObserver.mm
▸ Compiling RCTI18nManager.mm
▸ Compiling RCTExceptionsManager.mm
▸ Compiling RCTDeviceInfo.mm
▸ Compiling RCTDevSplitBundleLoader.mm
▸ Compiling RCTDevSettings.mm
▸ Compiling RCTDevMenu.mm
▸ Compiling RCTDevLoadingView.mm
▸ Compiling RCTClipboard.mm
▸ Compiling RCTAsyncLocalStorage.mm
▸ Compiling RCTAppearance.mm
▸ Compiling RCTAppState.mm
▸ Compiling RCTAlertManager.mm
▸ Compiling RCTActionSheetManager.mm
▸ Running script 'Start Packager'
▸ Linking QuickPass
⚠️  ld: method '+UIDatePickerMode:' in category from /Users/sqtc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuickPass-faybjdvqxbotkeajwmmcoupclnpg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/React-Core/React.framework/React(RCTDatePickerManager.o) conflicts with same method from another category
▸ Running script 'Bundle React Native code and images'
    the transform cache was reset.
▸ Processing Info.plist
▸ Running script '[CP] Copy Pods Resources'
▸ Running script '[CP-User] [RNFB] Core Configuration'
      A firebase.json file was not found, whilst this file is optional it is recommended to include it to configure firebase services in React Native Firebase.
▸ Generating 'QuickPass.app.dSYM'
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening QuickPass.xcworkspace.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I then tried to create new signing profiles. Created new CSRs in my device and uploaded them to developer.apple.com and created new development certificates. But the same error occurs.

My device informations:

- Development machine: macOS Big Sur (11.4)
- XCode: 13.2.1 (13C100)
- Device: iOS 14.1